# Convergence of a sum to the integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-analysis, integration, limits-and-convergence, periodic-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a 1-periodic function. I am looking about the conditions on $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that we have the property :
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}f(a+b\ell)\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\int_0^1 f(x)dx.$$
Thank you for your help !

Comment: It might depend on $f$ (and if $f$ is not integrable then the RHS
doesn't even exist...).  It is well known that the limit holds for
*every* continuous $f$ **iff** $b$ is irrational; one very fruitful
approach is via Weyl's equidistribution criterion.


Answer (score 5, accepted):

This follows from Weyl's equidistribution theorem.  When $b$ is irrational, convergence holds whenever $f$ is continuous, or even just Riemann-integrable (see http://individual.utoronto.ca/hannigandaley/equidistribution.pdf for an exposition).  Integrability is not enough by itself, since you can make the sum zero by changing $f$ on the countable set $\{a+b\ell\}$, which has measure zero.

When $b$ is rational, convergence certainly doesn't hold for most $f$, since $a+b\ell$ takes on just finitely many values modulo $1$.

Comment: Actually, rational $b$ is not so bad, if $f$ is continuous and you choose $a$ carefully.